# Can I remove "/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH..." to success with import?

Tags: mysql, import

I'm trying to import a database and get this message (Swedish lang phpMyadmin):

[image]

As you see, I get the message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AUTO_INCREMENT=140059' at line 10

So I guess the problem is:

```
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH ( `feeditemsID` + YEAR(`feeddate`)) PARTITIONS 3 */
```

That is right before the auto_increment code. Here is the whole code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `feeditems` (
   `feeditemsID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `companyID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `fucID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `feedID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `description` text NOT NULL,
   `url` text NOT NULL,
   `feeddate` datetime NOT NULL,
   `region` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `jobtype` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `jobinfomisc` text NOT NULL,
   `joblastdate` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `jobcontactname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `jobcontactphone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `jobcontactmail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `jobcontactinfo` text NOT NULL,
   `jobworkers` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `jobActive` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `logo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `infokus` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `deleted` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`feeditemsID`,`feeddate`),
   KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
   KEY `companyID` (`companyID`),
   KEY `feedID` (`feedID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH ( `feeditemsID` + YEAR(`feeddate`))
PARTITIONS 3 */ AUTO_INCREMENT=331451 ;
```

So the question is, can I just remove that part? Or what can be wrong? I'm not that good at stuffs like this. Would be happy for help here.

Comment: Please post the whole code. The part which throws the error is missing.

Comment: @tombom Done. So, please check now again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When code starts with something like this

```
/*!50100
```

the code following till `*/` is executed only, when MySQL is installed in a version above 5.0.100

The error here is, that you're mixing table options with partition options.

From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html):

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    (create_definition,...)
    [table_options]
    [partition_options]
...

table_option:
    ENGINE [=] engine_name
  | AUTO_INCREMENT [=] value
  | AVG_ROW_LENGTH [=] value
  | [DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET [=] charset_name
...

partition_options:
    PARTITION BY
        { [LINEAR] HASH(expr)
        | [LINEAR] KEY(column_list)
        | RANGE(expr)
        | LIST(expr) }
    [PARTITIONS num]
    [SUBPARTITION BY
        { [LINEAR] HASH(expr)
        | [LINEAR] KEY(column_list) }
      [SUBPARTITIONS num]
    ]
    [(partition_definition [, partition_definition] ...)]
```

So, try it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `feeditems` (
   `feeditemsID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `companyID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `fucID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `feedID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `description` text NOT NULL,
   `url` text NOT NULL,
   `feeddate` datetime NOT NULL,
   `region` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `jobtype` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `jobinfomisc` text NOT NULL,
   `joblastdate` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `jobcontactname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `jobcontactphone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `jobcontactmail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `jobcontactinfo` text NOT NULL,
   `jobworkers` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `jobActive` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `logo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `infokus` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `deleted` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`feeditemsID`,`feeddate`),
   KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
   KEY `companyID` (`companyID`),
   KEY `feedID` (`feedID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=331451
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH ( `feeditemsID` + YEAR(`feeddate`))
PARTITIONS 3 */;
```